# Detect/Block SendKeys.Send key messages

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I was wondering if there was a way to detect if key strokes are from the keyboard or a SendKeys.Send call.

I would like to block specific SendKeys.Send keys but if those keys are directly from the keyboard then let them go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a console application and run the code located here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx

Create a second application that will fire `SendKeys.Send` when you click a button.  You will notice that the first console application detects key strokes from the keyboard but not keys from `SendKeys.Send`

I'm sure you could you use the code from the article to detect if the keystroke came from the keyboard or `SendKeys.Send`